# Conditional Display Visualforce Page from Visualforce Tab

Tags: visualforce, tab

I am trying to display two visualforce page from a single visualforce tab.On my first click of tab i should display vfpage1 and then on wards it should display vfpage2..please share your knowledge

Thanks

Comment: What did you try ? Can you show us your code ?

Comment: I have no idea..i am working on it..

Comment: are you talking about something like Splash page...